# What are the difference between R-tree and R*-tree? and Why a like-R-tree inserts with rectangles?

Tags: data-structures, r-tree

> Could anyone tell me what's the difference between R-tree and R*-tree?

One question more,

> Why a like-R-tree inserts with rectangles? what are the advantages and disadvantages about that?

Comment: Please read the **R*-tree paper**. Since it builds on top of the R-tree, it will only discuss the differences.

Answer (score 1):

Perfect explanation:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree

vs.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R*_tree